# How to remove a specific characters in an emails lines before the @?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-3, sublime-text-2, notepad

**How to remove any characters that aren't of the following from email lines before the @, through regular expressions?**

I tried the following but it didn't work :(

Find what: `^([^a-z0-9;:]*)([a-z0-9]*)(?1)(.*?[;:].+$)`

Replace with: `$2$3`

Characters to keep in any position before the @:

`| Letters | Numbers | - | _ | . |`

**Sample Lines:**

```
1my.tes~t@gmail.com:Testing1
my.tes!2t@gmail.com:tEsting1
m#y3.test@gmail.com:teSting1
m4y.tes(t@gmail.com:tesTing1
my.5test\@gmail.com:testIng1
my-tes6(t@gmail.com:testiNg1
my_t7e+st@gmail.com:testinG1
&my_t%est8=@gmail.com:TestinG1
```

**Result Needed:**

```
1my.test@email.com:Testing1
my.tes2t@email.com:tEsting1
my3.test@email.com:teSting1
m4y.test@email.com:tesTing1
my.5Test@email.com:testIng1
my-tes6t@email.com:testiNg1
my_t7est@email.com:testinG1
my_test8@email.com:TestinG1
```

Answer (score 0):

These special characters cannot occur after the `@` character in the domain
name, so you would be safe by just deleting the special character
`~ ! # + % & = \ (` (add more as required).

If you would like to do that by one replace operation, use these:

Find what: `~|!|#|\+|%|&|=|\\|\(`
Replace with: Nothing (meaning empty to delete)

Here is what this gives on your example data:

[image]

Comment: But i want to ignore what after the @ and as well what after the :

Because there might be a special characters in the line that after : that i want to keep

For example my_test8@gmail.com:Te$stin.G%1  << will get removed which i want to keep

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^\r\n\w.-]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^\r\n\w.-]+    # 1 or more any character that is not word character [a-zA-Z0-9_] or dot or hyphen
```

**Replacement:**

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]